# google not crawling a SPA as expected

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, google-crawlers, prerender

I'm using prerender.io, it's working perfectly with other crawlers such as Facebook.

But when I ask google to fetch and render my links on the webmaster tools it seems to not fetch correctly even though it renders correctly.

To clarify, the image preview of the website in the **Rendering** tab is correct but on the **Fetching** tab the code is still not rendered like so:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{head.name}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{head.description}}" />
```

On google search results what is displayed is text from the what looks like rendered page, some of it not visible (like not open drop-downs) and not available before render also.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch as Google has a known issue where it doesn't follow the escaped fragment crawling protocol (even though Googlebot does correctly follow it).

Try passing in the `_escaped_fragment_` URL to Fetch as Google.